# Google GWT Chart Tool set the space gap between bars

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

Anyone know whether it is possible to specify the space/grap between two bars in GWT-Chart-tool library?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `bar.groupWidth` setting (see [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options) for more details).

```
Options options = Options.create();
Options barOptions = Options.create();
barOptions.set('groupWidth','20%');
options.set('bar',barOptions);
```

pass the `options` instance to the `draw` function of your `BarChart`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gwt-Highchart](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/) and with [PoinPaddind](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointPadding) and PointWidth* you can do what you want.

- api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointWidth